# Automatic selection of GCC optimization options using a gene weighted genetic algorithm

Tags: linux, gcc, genetic-algorithm, compiler-optimization

I'm doing a project for handling gcc compiler optimization options automatically without  programmer specification. I decided to use the Travelling salesman algorithm and GA for selecting the best optimization based on speed of execution. This application would take a problem (C++ code) as input and do permutation combination on all the available optimization options in GCC compiler and store the time taken for execution.

Now, is it possible to program this in a Shell Script? or do i have to program in C++ itself?

Heres a link to the base paper.
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4625477

Please let me know if I'm wrong about the whole concept. It would be very helpful if u could lead me in the right path and suggest anything.

Thankyou.

Comment: http://freecode.com/projects/acovea does something like that

Comment: I am not sure, but I remember a group that already performed this approach. I cant find it with a quick look on the gcc page, maybe you should have a look in the gcc mailing archive.

Comment: You can generate a file containing a list of optimization sequences you want to test

Answer (score 1):

The Milepost [Ctuning](http://ctuning.org) project worked exactly on that (Grigori Fursin, Albert Cohen, both at INRIA), using machine learning techniques to tune GCC optimizations.

You could use [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extensions to do likewise.

Answer (score 0):

I think this categorically proves the age-old proposal that GCC has far too many options.

As for answering your specific question, though, I think you are going about doing something that, in the end, isn't of very much value.  One of the main problems is that your resulting gene will only be good for a specific architecture, environment and gcc version.

Also, I'm pretty sure someone familiar with GCC would be better than your algorithm in most real-life cases.

I don't mean to rain on your parade or anything, it's certainly an interesting technical/intellectual exercise.  I'd write a C/C++ program that output a shell script/command line then ran the resultant script/command line, timed it, and stored the time it took to run *and the correctness of the result*.  Some optimisations may cause certain code to execute differently, resulting in an incorrect result.  Make sure your test-case is outputting numerical data so you can calculate how close your optimised program got to the result you were expecting.

Your test-cases will never cover enough ground, here, and your fitness function is going to be mostly guesswork (since it'll depend a lot upon what other processes were running on the machine at the time and what they were doing).  It will take a *long* time to evolve.

Comment: Actually I have thought about the lags and accuracy issues concerning this type of application especially because of large number of test cases. But apart from those issues, is it possible to program something like this by minimizing the number of test cases? And the output is focussed at one type of architecture/platform. I had no hopes on the topic when my senior gave me the project. But i have no choice other than to do it. Thnx again.

Comment: The number of test-cases you use is a trade-off between time taken to run a generation and accuracy of result.  Also, the size and complexity of each test-case.  I'd go for few large, complex test-cases rather than lots of small, simple ones though as I believe that's gonna be your lowest overhead and best end-result (real-life code is more likely to be large and complex).  Throw in one or two small ones as well though, to make sure the algorithm scales well to smaller inputs (if that is a constraint).